# Extracting specific columns from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, r-faq

I have an R data frame with 6 columns, and I want to create a new dataframe that only has three of the columns.

Assuming my data frame is `df`, and I want to extract columns `A`, `B`, and `E`, this is the only command I can figure out:

```
 data.frame(df$A,df$B,df$E)
```

Is there a more compact way of doing this?

Comment: `select(df, c('A','B','C'))`

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Using the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package, if your data.frame is called `df1`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  select(A, B, E)
```

This can also be written without the `%>%` pipe as:

```
select(df1, A, B, E)
```

Comment: Given the considerably evolution of the Tidyverse since posting my question, I've switched the answer to you.

Comment: Given the furious rate of change in the tidyverse, I would caution against using this pattern. This is in addition to my strong preference against treating column names as if they are object names when writing code for functions, packages, or applications.

Comment: It has been over four years since this answer was submitted, and the pattern hasn't changed. Piped expressions can be quite intuitive, which is why they are appealing.

Comment: how do I execute a further command onto this subset? E.g. I want to compute the rowMean: "df1 %>% rowMeans(select(A, B, E))" does not work.

Comment: You'd chain together a pipeline like: `df1 %>% select(A, B, E) %>% rowMeans(.)`.  See the documentation for the `%>%` pipe by typing `?magrittr::\`%>%\``

Comment: This is a useful solution, but for the example given in the question, Josh's answer is more readable, faster, and dependency free. I hope new users learn square bracket subsetting before diving in the tidyverse :)!

Comment: `select(df, c('A','B','C'))`

Comment: Worth mentioning there are a host of [tidyselect helper functions](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html) that are very useful for selecting columns so you do not have to type out all the names.

Answer (score 520):

You can subset using a vector of column names. I strongly prefer this approach over those that treat column names as if they are object names (e.g. `subset()`), especially when programming in functions, packages, or applications.

```
# data for reproducible example
# (and to avoid confusion from trying to subset `stats::df`)
df <- setNames(data.frame(as.list(1:5)), LETTERS[1:5])
# subset
df[c("A","B","E")]
```

Note there's no comma (i.e. it's not `df[,c("A","B","C")]`). That's because `df[,"A"]` returns a vector, not a data frame. But `df["A"]` will always return a data frame.

```
str(df["A"])
## 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
## $ A: int 1
str(df[,"A"])  # vector
##  int 1
```

---

Thanks to [David Dorchies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085806/extracting-specific-columns-from-a-data-frame/10085807?noredirect=1#comment64615934_10085807) for pointing out that `df[,"A"]` returns a vector instead of a data.frame, and to [Antoine Fabri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270475/moody-mudskipper) for suggesting a better alternative (above) to my original solution (below).

```
# subset (original solution--not recommended)
df[,c("A","B","E")]  # returns a data.frame
df[,"A"]             # returns a vector
```

Comment: That gives the error `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`.

Comment: @ArenCambre: then your data.frame isn't really named `df`. `df` is also a function in the stats package.

Comment: @ArenCambre: 
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-XU9PduVhq-I/Um-Y6e19jZI/AAAAAAAADfI/PrmoFQexa5M/s1600/Book+last+page.jpg

Comment: but why this one doesn't work `df[,-c("A","B","E")]`?

Comment: @Cina: Because `-"A"` is a syntax error. And `?Extract` says, "`i`, `j`, `...` can also be negative integers, indicating elements/slices to leave out of the selection."

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when I use this.

Comment: @Richard: I don't know what to tell you; it's most certainly valid syntax. I've also added a reproducible example.

Comment: There is an issue with this syntax because if we extract only one column R, returns a vector instead of a dataframe and this could be unwanted: `> df[,c("A")]` `[1] 1`. Using `subset` doesn't have this disadvantage.

Comment: I noticed that using a character vector of names of columns often doesn't work when I have the package `data.table` loaded.  In those cases, it's better to use one of the other methods, either `subset()` or dplyr's `select()`.

Comment: @PauldeBarros: whether `data.table` is loaded should not matter, unless the *object* you're trying to subset is a `data.table` and not a `data.frame`. This question is about subsetting a `data.frame`, not a `data.table`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: I'm sure you're right.  The objects that create problems are of class data.frame and data.table (according to `str`).  Without data.table loaded, those same objects are just data.frames.  I didn't realize that loading data.table befote running my code would change the class of  those objects.  The fact that the method you provided (and which I had been using)  suddenly stopped working was surprising to me, and I thought others might benefit from knowing that the behavior of their code might change in that circumstance.

Comment: Maybe better `df[c("A","B","E")]` (without comma) ? we win one character and we address the issue that @david-dorchies pointed out

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Better is to set argument `drop = FALSE`: `df[, "A", drop = FALSE]`.

Comment: With list subsetting, the drop argument is unnecessary, that's what I meant. `df["A"]` is fine.

Answer (score 117):

This is the role of the [`subset()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/subset.html) function:

```
> dat <- data.frame(A=c(1,2),B=c(3,4),C=c(5,6),D=c(7,7),E=c(8,8),F=c(9,9)) 
> subset(dat, select=c("A", "B"))
  A B
1 1 3
2 2 4
```

Comment: When I try this, with my data, I get the error:
" Error in x[j] : invalid subscript type 'list' "

But if c("A", "B") isn't a list, what is it?

Comment: @Rafael_Espericueta Hard to guess without viewing your code... But `c("A", "B")` is a vector, not a list.

Comment: It convert data frame to list.

Comment: `subset()` works with naked variable names too : `subset(dat, select = c(A, B))`,  A and B here will be treated as numeric indices, similar to what tidy selection does.

Answer (score 92):

There are two obvious choices:  Joshua Ulrich's `df[,c("A","B","E")]` or

```
df[,c(1,2,5)]
```

as in

```
> df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2),B=c(3,4),C=c(5,6),D=c(7,7),E=c(8,8),F=c(9,9)) 
> df
  A B C D E F
1 1 3 5 7 8 9
2 2 4 6 7 8 9
> df[,c(1,2,5)]
  A B E
1 1 3 8
2 2 4 8
> df[,c("A","B","E")]
  A B E
1 1 3 8
2 2 4 8
```

Answer (score 21):

Where df1 is your original data frame:

```
df2 <- subset(df1, select = c(1, 2, 5))
```

Comment: This doesn't use `dplyr`. It uses `base::subset`, and is identical to [Stephane Laurent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10086494/903061) except that you use column numbers instead of column names.

Answer (score 21):

For some reason only

```
df[, (names(df) %in% c("A","B","E"))]
```

worked for me. All of the above syntaxes yielded "undefined columns selected".

Answer (score 15):

You can also use the `sqldf` package which performs selects on R data frames as :

```
df1 <- sqldf("select A, B, E from df")
```

This gives as the output a data frame `df1` with columns: A, B ,E.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `with` :

```
with(df, data.frame(A, B, E))
```

Answer (score 0):

`[`  and subset are not substitutable:

`[` does return a vector if only one column is selected.

```
df = data.frame(a="a",b="b")    

identical(
  df[,c("a")], 
  subset(df,select="a")
) 

identical(
  df[,c("a","b")],  
  subset(df,select=c("a","b"))
)
```

Comment: Not if you set `drop=FALSE`. Example: `df[,c("a"),drop=F]`

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

If you are using a tibble (commonly used in the tidyverse) you can safely do any of the following to select columns and you will get a tibble back:

```r
library(tibble)
tb <- tibble(A = 1:2, B = 3:4)

# By index
tb[1]
tb[, 1]

tb[1:2]
tb[, 1:2]


# By name
tb["A"]
tb[, "A"]

tb[c("A", "B")]
tb[, c("A", "B")]
```

This is in addition to the answer given by @Sam Firke which uses the popular `select()` verb for column selection.

You can use any of these selection operators on base R data frames, but know there are some cases where you should specify `drop = FALSE`.

---

There is already some discussion about tidyverse versus base R in other answers, but hopefully this adds something.

You can see from the documentation `` ?`[.data.frame` `` (and the answer from @Joshua Ulrich) that data frame columns can be selected several ways. This has to do with the `drop` argument:

> If `TRUE` the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension. The
> default is to drop if only one column is left, but not to drop if only
> one row is left.

If a single vector is given, then columns are indexed and selection behaves like list selection (the `drop` argument of `[` is ignored). In this case, a data frame is always returned:

```r
df <- data.frame(A = 1:2, B = 3:4)

str(df[1])
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ A: int  1 2

str(df[1:2])
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ A: int  1 2
#  $ B: int  3 4

str(df[c("A", "B")])
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ A: int  1 2
#  $ B: int  3 4
```

However, if two indicies are given (`[row, column]`) then selection behaves more like matrix selection. In this case the default argument of `[` is `drop = TRUE` so the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension *only* if there is only a single column left:

```r
str(df[1, ]) # single row selection (does not reduce dimension)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ A: int 1
#  $ B: int 3

str(df[, 1]) # single column selection (does reduce dimension)
# int [1:2] 1 2
```

Of course you can always change the default behavior by setting `drop = FALSE`:

```r
str(df[, 1, drop = FALSE])
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ A: int  1 2
```

---

In the tidyverse, tibbles are preferred. They are like data frames, but have a few significant differences -- one being column selection. Column selection using tibbles never reduces dimensionality, as shown above:

```r
library(tibble)

tb <- as_tibble(df)
class(tb)
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

str(tb[, 1])
# tibble [2 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  $ A: int [1:2] 1 2

str(tb[1])
# tibble [2 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  $ A: int [1:2] 1 2
```

All the other tibble column selection works as you would expect (above only shows by index, but you can select by name too).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to **remove** columns you do not want than selecting ones that you do. This can be done by using the `-` operator for indexes, `setdiff` or `subset` by name, or `!` for logical vectors in base R:

```r
# Column index
df[-c(3, 4)]

# Column name
subset(df, select = -c(C, D))
df[setdiff(names(df), c("C", "D"))]

# Logical vector
df[!names(df) %in% c("C", "D")]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df<- dplyr::select ( df,A,B,C)
```

Also, you can assign a different name to the newly created data

```
data<- dplyr::select ( df,A,B,C)
```

Comment: This was already in the accepted answer