# How to extract data from dataframe and make new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a df (300000 obs by 15 var). A simplified version looks like this:

```
    Col1        Col2 
1   TRGV3*01    YCAVWIGSTSWVKIFA

2   TRGV7*02    YCASWAGQSGSGFHKVFA

3   TRGV7*02    YCASWAGRGSGFHKVFA

4   TRGV3*01    YCAVWINLGTSWVKIFA

5   TRGV3*01    YCAVWSGTSWVKIFA

6   TRGV7*02    YCASWAGRESSGFHKVFA

7   TRGV7*02    YCASWAVYSSGFHKVFA

8   TRGV7*02    YCASWSSSGFHKVFA

9   TRGV2*01    YCAVWICGTSWVKIFA
```

I want to subset the df and create a new df such that for a particular value in col1 (TRGV7*02), all possible values of Col2 are subsetted and the output is something like this:

```
TRGV7*02                 TRGV3*01                     TRGV2*01

YCASWAGQSGSGFHKVFA       YCAVWIGSTSWVKIFA             YCAVWICGTSWVKIFA

YCASWAGRGSGFHKVFA        YCAVWSGTSWVKIFA    

YCAVWINLGTSWVKIFA       

YCASWAGRESSGFHKVFA      

YCASWAVYSSGFHKVFA       

YCASWSSSGFHKVFA
```

Once I do this I need to do some analysis and I can't figure out how to do that either...
1. Spit out another df from the one just created above with the same format but only with all unique values in that particular column (lot of repeats in the original dataset)
2. Compare the values generated in each column above and figure out which values in each column are unique compared to the values in all the columns or when just trying to compare it with one other column.

Hope that made sense. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: see : [Here][1] - Extracting specific columns from a data frame


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085806/extracting-specific-columns-from-a-data-frame

Comment: That link refers to just splitting out whole columns. I need to make 1 column into the row titles and list all values for that row. 

Alos, any idea how to do the next steps I mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution (if the column order doesn't metter, you can skip the `setcolorder` part)

```
library(data.table)
setcolorder(dcast(setDT(df), Col2 ~ Col1)[, 
          lapply(.SD, sort, na.last = TRUE), .SDcols = -c("Col2")], 
          c("TRGV7*02", "TRGV3*01", "TRGV2*01"))[]
#              TRGV7*02          TRGV3*01         TRGV2*01
# 1: YCASWAGQSGSGFHKVFA  YCAVWIGSTSWVKIFA YCAVWICGTSWVKIFA
# 2: YCASWAGRESSGFHKVFA YCAVWINLGTSWVKIFA               NA
# 3:  YCASWAGRGSGFHKVFA   YCAVWSGTSWVKIFA               NA
# 4:  YCASWAVYSSGFHKVFA                NA               NA
# 5:    YCASWSSSGFHKVFA                NA               NA
# 6:                 NA                NA               NA
# 7:                 NA                NA               NA
# 8:                 NA                NA               NA
# 9:                 NA                NA               NA
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but I keep getting an error: col1 = v.TRV for me and col2 = x.CDR3

> setcolorder(dcast(setDT(gamma.TRVfilt), x.CDR3 ~ v.TRV)[,
+     lapply(.SD, sort, na.last = TRUE), .SDcols = -c("x.CDR3")], 
+     c("TRGV1*02", "TRGV1*04", "TRGV1*05", "TRGV1*06", "TRGV1*07", "TRGV2*01", "TRGV2*02", "TRGV4*01", "TRGV4*04", "TRGV5*01", "TRGV6*02", "TRGV7*02"))[]


Using num as value column: use value.var to override.
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
Error in `[.data.frame`(dcast(setDT(gamma.TRVfilt), x.CDR3 ~ v.TRV), ,  : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = -c("x.CDR3"))

Comment: Did you load the `data.table` package? Also, does just `dcast(setDT(gamma.TRVfilt), x.CDR3 ~ v.TRV)[, lapply(.SD, sort, na.last = TRUE), .SDcols = -c("x.CDR3")]` works?

Comment: Get the following error.


Using num as value column: use value.var to override.
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
Error in `[.data.frame`(dcast(setDT(gamma.TRVfilt), x.CDR3 ~ v.TRV), ,  : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = -c("x.CDR3"))


By doing:
> format= dcast(gamma.TRVfilt, x.CDR3 ~ v.TRV, value.var="num", fun.aggregate=sum, na.rm=TRUE)

I get a matrix with values in the cell using some values off the original df. Don't knw how you got the actual values of Col2 (x.CDR3) instead of the numeric values its picking up. Something to do with .SDcols...? that I don't get :/

Comment: Yes. THis is what I get 




Get the following error. Using num as value column: use value.var to override. Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length Error in [.data.frame(dcast(setDT(gamma.TRVfilt), x.CDR3 ~ v.TRV), , : unused argument (.SDcols = -c("x.CDR3"))

Comment: The data that you provided don't have these columns. It only has `Col1` and `Col2`.

Comment: Same issue. 
setcolorder(dcast(setDT(df), Col2 ~ Col1)[,lapply(.SD, sort, na.last = TRUE), .SDcols = -c("Col2")], 
+ c("TRGV7*02", "TRGV3*01", "TRGV2*01"))[]



Using Col2 as value column: use value.var to override.
Error in `[.data.frame`(dcast(setDT(df), Col2 ~ Col1), , lapply(.SD, sort,  : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = -c("Col2"))

Comment: What `data.table` version do you have?

Comment: I'm updating on R studio on mac. It didn't show that there was a newer version available but will let you know if it installs regardless in a bit. In the meantime, could you please tell me how you got the col2 values to fill the matrix instead of a numeric variable value?

Comment: I've got 1.9.4(had some trouble) But getting the same error. Using num as value column: use value.var to override.
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
Error in `[.data.frame`(dcast(setDT(gamma.TRVfilt), x.CDR3 ~ v.TRV), ,  : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = -c("x.CDR3"))

Comment: Did you `library(data.table)` ?

Comment: Just doing format=dcast(df, Col2~Col1) works fine - but I end up with NAs. Using your code, keep getting the "unused argument (.SDcols = -c("Col2")) error. Thank you so much btw!

Comment: I don't know. This works perfectly fine on the data you provided. If you can provide a data that this code fails on, it could be usefull

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `split`ting one column by the other, and then using `stri_list2matrix` from the "stringi" package to convert the resulting `list` to a `matrix`. Once the data are in a `list`, you can also use `lapply` to do any filtering or sorting you might want to do on each list item.

Here's an example (assuming your source `data.frame` is called "mydf"). I've separated it out into 4 steps so you can see what's happening, but it's possible with more compact code.

```
library(stringi)
A <- with(mydf, split(Col2, Col1))          # (1) Split col1 by col2
B <- lapply(A, function(x) sort(unique(x))) # (2) Extract unique and sort
C <- stri_list2matrix(B)                    # (3) Convert to matrix
colnames(C) <- names(B)                     # (4) Add column names
C
#      TRGV2*01           TRGV3*01            TRGV7*02            
# [1,] "YCAVWICGTSWVKIFA" "YCAVWIGSTSWVKIFA"  "YCASWAGQSGSGFHKVFA"
# [2,] NA                 "YCAVWINLGTSWVKIFA" "YCASWAGRESSGFHKVFA"
# [3,] NA                 "YCAVWSGTSWVKIFA"   "YCASWAGRGSGFHKVFA" 
# [4,] NA                 NA                  "YCASWAVYSSGFHKVFA" 
# [5,] NA                 NA                  "YCASWSSSGFHKVFA"
```