# Selecting columns based on pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

**Possible duplicate:**
 [Extracting specific columns from a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085806/extracting-specific-columns-from-a-data-frame)

I have a data frame that follows a pattern in the columns. Here I have some 10 columns but actually in the final data frame the number of columns is not know as it depends on the data given.

```
  V1    V2   V3          V4       V5   V6          V7     V8    V9          V10           
ADAM32  P 0.001000000   40.61038  P 0.001000000   40.61038  P 0.001000000   40.61038
CCL5    P 0.000491000 6546.20000  P 0.000491000 6546.20000  P 0.000491000 6546.20000
CILP2   A 0.500000024   92.66398  A 0.500000024   92.66398  A 0.500000024   92.66398
EPHB3   P 0.000562000  461.30000  P 0.000562000  461.30000  P 0.000562000  461.30000
GUCA1A  P 0.002006000    9.40000  P 0.002006000    9.40000  P 0.002006000    9.40000
HSPA6   P 0.000322000  564.00000  P 0.000322000  564.00000  P 0.000322000  564.00000
MAPK1   P 0.002000000  435.00000  P 0.002000000  435.00000  P 0.002000000  435.00000
PIGX    P 0.003822926  411.38856  P 0.003822926  411.38856  P 0.003822926  411.38856
PTPN21  M 0.051040220   94.30000  M 0.051040220   94.30000  M 0.051040220   94.30000
THRA    M 0.054470000  151.10000  M 0.054470000  151.10000  M 0.054470000  151.10000
UBA7    P 0.000468000  845.60000  P 0.000468000  845.60000  P 0.000468000  845.60000
WFDC2   P 0.005475547  177.61689  P 0.005475547  177.61689  P 0.005475547  177.61689
7-Mar   P 0.000673000  643.20000  P 0.000673000  643.20000  P 0.000673000  643.20000
```

In the above data frame I want the first two columns and then column after two columns, column after two columns and so on in the same fashion. Therefore I want v1,v2,v5,v8 and so on till the data frame is exhausted. So if I have a data frame of 1000 columns in the same pattern, how can I select the columns?

The expected output:

```
     V1 V2  V5  V8
 ADAM32  P   P  P
   CCL5  P   P  P 
  CILP2  A   A  A
  EPHB3  P   P  P
 GUCA1A  P   P  P
  HSPA6  P   P  P
  MAPK1  P   P  P
   PIGX  P   P  P
 PTPN21  M   M  M
   THRA  M   M  M
   UBA7  P   P  P
  WFDC2  P   P  P
  7-Mar  P   P  P
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the criterion is to select only colomuns which are not numeric, you can use filter:

```
Filter(Negate(is.numeric), df)
```

Example on dummy data:

```
df = data.frame('a','b',1,2,'c',23,45.0,'c')
Filter(function(u) !is.numeric(u), df)
#  X.a. X.b. X.c. X.c..1
#1    a    b    c      c
```

To select the first column, the second, the fifth, the eight and so on, you can also try:

```
df[,c(1,(1:ceiling(length(df)/3))*3-1)]
```

Comment: By the way nice thought.. i think its quite pretty.

Comment: it's an alternative proposal, but elegant only if you're sure your figures are effectively numeric and not formated as character ;)

Comment: thks akrun, this is effectively awsome this way!

Comment: My data frame was in character format, then i changed  to numeric .. so it works fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, this implicit check is needed. It's another criteria than selecting the sequence, but quite neat! Glad to help!

Comment: you mean `Negate(is.numeric)` ? It speaks by itself: you check is the element is numeric and negate this last result. So the function return True on a non numeric element: `Negate(is.numeric)('a')`

Comment: I mean about last line of code that u added. `df[,c(1,(1:ceiling(length(df)/3))*3-1)]`

Comment: Ah, you want column 1 and then `2, 5, 8, 11 .... = 3-1, 6-1, 9-1, 12-1 ... = 3*(1 ,2, 3, 4...) - 1`. But it's preferable to use `c(1,2,seq(5,ncol(df),3))`, more readable as @LyzandeR proposed. Beeing a mathematician, I tend to write done formulas ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `seq` function can help with this in the following way:

```
df <- read.table('clipboard',header=T)

df[, c(1,2,seq(5,ncol(df),3))]

       V1 V2 V5 V8
1  ADAM32  P  P  P
2    CCL5  P  P  P
3   CILP2  A  A  A
4   EPHB3  P  P  P
5  GUCA1A  P  P  P
6   HSPA6  P  P  P
7   MAPK1  P  P  P
8    PIGX  P  P  P
9  PTPN21  M  M  M
10   THRA  M  M  M
11   UBA7  P  P  P
12  WFDC2  P  P  P
13  7-Mar  P  P  P
```

Essentially `seq` creates the sequence as you want it i.e. starts from 5 until the total number of columns and returns a column index every two columns. In this I just added the first and second columns as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. U code gives the result as expected but throws the below warning; `Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'clipboard'`

Comment: I copied your example data (which saved it in the clipboard) and then used `read.table` with the first argument being the 'clipboard'; i.e. I essentially read your sample table. Make sure you do the same otherwise I don't know what will be stored in the clipboard :)