# Extracting specific selected columns to new DataFrame as a copy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, chained-assignment

I have a pandas DataFrame with 4 columns and I want to create a **new** DataFrame that **only** has three of the columns.  This question is similar to: [Extracting specific columns from a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085806/extracting-specific-columns-from-a-data-frame) but for pandas not R. The following code does not work, raises an error, and is certainly not the pandas way to do it.

```py
import pandas as pd
old = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [4,5], 'B' : [10,20], 'C' : [100,50], 'D' : [-30,-50]})
new = pd.DataFrame(zip(old.A, old.C, old.D)) 
# raises TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator
```

What is the pandas way to do it?

Comment: I would like to see a solution that works also if two columns are the same. For example: A, B, B..

Answer (score 682, accepted):

There is a way of doing this and it actually looks similar to R

```
new = old[['A', 'C', 'D']].copy()
```

Here you are just selecting the columns you want from the original data frame and creating a variable for those. If you want to modify the new dataframe at all you'll probably want to use `.copy()` to avoid a `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

An alternative method is to use `filter` which will create a copy by default:

```
new = old.filter(['A','B','D'], axis=1)
```

Finally, depending on the number of columns in your original dataframe, it might be more succinct to express this using a `drop` (this will also create a copy by default):

```
new = old.drop('B', axis=1)
```

Comment: A caution if just copying one column: In `old[['A']].copy()`, the double square brackets are required to create a new data frame. Note that `old['A'].copy()` will only create a Series.

Comment: Thank you for this amazing explanation. I was having a lot of trouble with creating new columns (after creating a new dataframe without the copy method). Stumped me. You answer finally helped me get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 62):

The easiest way is

```
new = old[['A','C','D']]
```

.

Comment: This isn't making a copy unless you explicitly call .copy()

Comment: this copies by default.

Comment: @Nguaial the behaviour of simple indexing is not specified. You will not know if you get a copy or a view. See documentation for more details:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, this will create a view and not a copy.

Answer (score 21):

Another simpler way seems to be:

```
new = pd.DataFrame([old.A, old.B, old.C]).transpose()
```

where `old.column_name` will give you a series. 
Make a list of all the column-series you want to retain and pass it to the DataFrame constructor. We need to do a transpose to adjust the shape.

```
In [14]:pd.DataFrame([old.A, old.B, old.C]).transpose()
Out[14]: 
   A   B    C
0  4  10  100
1  5  20   50
```

Comment: works, but not if column_name has special characters.

Comment: oh had not thought of that

Comment: @jimh in that case you can do old['column_name'] I believe

Comment: @Liz yes, but that is not in the solution

Answer (score 16):

columns by index:

```
# selected column index: 1, 6, 7
new = old.iloc[: , [1, 6, 7]].copy()
```

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative:

```
new = pd.DataFrame().assign(A=old['A'], C=old['C'], D=old['D'])
```

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell, you don't necessarily need to specify the axis when using the filter function.

```
new = old.filter(['A','B','D'])
```

returns the same dataframe as

```
new = old.filter(['A','B','D'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Generic functional form**

```
def select_columns(data_frame, column_names):
    new_frame = data_frame.loc[:, column_names]
    return new_frame
```

**Specific for your problem above**

```
selected_columns = ['A', 'C', 'D']
new = select_columns(old, selected_columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a new data frame then:

```
import pandas as pd
old = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [4,5], 'B' : [10,20], 'C' : [100,50], 'D' : [-30,-50]})
new=  old[['A', 'C', 'D']]
```

Comment: Dangerous; this isn't making a copy.

Comment: What's the diffrence between copy and copy of a slice of Dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can drop columns in the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1], 'B': [2, 2], 'C': [3, 3], 'D': [4, 4]})

df[df.columns.drop(['B', 'C'])]
```

or

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.drop(['B', 'C'])]
```

Output:

```
   A  D
0  1  4
1  1  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `get()` to create a new copy (that doesn't run into `SettingWithCopyWarning`).

```py
new = old.get(['A', 'C', 'D'])
```

Also, `filter` selects by column labels by default, so the following works.

```py
new = old.filter(['A', 'C', 'D'])
```

`axis=` is needed if one needs to select by row. For example, `old.filter([0], axis=0)` selects the first row.

If `new` is an already existing dataframe, then `assign()` also works (if you want to keep the old columns with their original column names).

```py
new = pd.DataFrame()
new = new.assign(**old[['A', 'C', 'D']])
```