# How i can create dataframe of specific interval columns by index number

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe of 130 columns, i wants to make df of each 10th column start from 0th  then 3rd column and then wants to add 10

for ex:

```
df.columns = [0,3,13,23,33,43,53,63,73,83,93,103,113,123]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using slicing

**Ex:**

```
columns = list(range(0, 131))     #sample column --> df.columns.tolist() 
result = [columns[0]] + columns[3::10]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 3, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53, 63, 73, 83, 93, 103, 113, 123]
```

---

To create new DF

```
new_df = df[result].copy()
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, can u suggest me what should be next step to make dataframe. i am trying new_df  =  pd.DataFrame(df, columns = result) but its showing NaN values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682828/extracting-specific-selected-columns-to-new-dataframe-as-a-copy

Comment: `new_df = df[result].copy()`

Comment: again its giving error,may be it copy by col lable name not by col index number

Comment: I used `list(range(0, 131))` as an example you should be using `df.columns.tolist()  `

Comment: yess...i got expected answer...thanku so much for your efforts