# Separate different parts of a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am a newbie and I have a csv file that contains account name of reddit, subreddit, time and message.

I read it with:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv("addres/train_data.csv", encoding="utf8")
```

if I write: 
`train_data.head()` I see

[image]

Do you know a way in which I can create an array with [author, body] ?

To begin  I have tried to create two array (author and messages) in this way:

```
train=open("addres/train_data.csv")
train.readline()
author=[]
message=[]
for line in train:
    autore,categoria,ora, messaggio=line.split(",")
    author.append(autore)
    message.append(messaggio)
```

But messages contains "," so it doesn't work properly.

Thank you and sorry for the silly question.

Comment: Instead of picture, post a testable fragment from `addres/train_data.csv` file

Comment: After reading with pandas: `train_data[['author', 'body']]`?

Comment: Use a context manager to handle files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_tmp = train_data[['author', 'body']] # allows you to select subset by column name
content_array = [list(x) for x in df_tmp.values] # a list of lists ([ith_author, ith_body])
```

Keep in mind that `df_tmp` is only a [view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11285613/5070837) of train_data, you might want to make a [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34682828/5070837) depending on what you intend to do with it. If you need the data to be immutable, you can use [tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9762084/5070837) instead.

Comment: Hi, thank you. One more question. Now I'm interested only on the messages and i have done as you have said and it is ok. I obtain a list: [["message1"], ["message2 "], etc ] . I want instead a thing like this: ["message1", "message2" etc...] how can I do?

Comment: Glad I could help. If the answer solves your problem, please *accept* it. As for how to flatten a list of lists into a list, please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/5070837) answer.