# How select certain columns and rows in R

Tags: r, xlsx

I upload .xlsx file into R and I wonder how to select certain columns and rows for data analysis, when data looks like this:

```
columnName1  columnName2  columnName3  columnName4
<NA>           NA            NA          <NA>
text           number        number       text
text           number        number       text
```

and the output should look like this:
(e.g. Select columnName2 and columnName3) with command print data you should see this:

```
number     number
number     number
```

Comment: What is your expected output? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085806/extracting-specific-columns-from-a-data-frame