# RShiny - accessing data inside reactive expression with selectInput

Tags: r, null, shiny

I want to create a shiny app interpolating weather data. When I try to access my data inside a reactive expression I always get as a result NULL. I don't know where I am wrong. I tried to imitate my problem as simple as possible. 
Here we go:

**My datatable:**

```
lon lat Temperature AirPressure
50.0 25.0 12.1 1012.0
51.0 26.0 13.4 1011.0
```

name of the datatalbe: `myDataTable`

**My ui.R:**

```
selectInput(inputId = "getData",
                label = "used Data:",
                choices = c("Temperature","AirPressure"),
                selected = "Temperature"
)
```

**Inside my reactive expression** I want to access the data depending on what is selected. Now when I do the following:

**1. Test**

```
print(myDataTable$Temperature)
```

Result (as expected): `[1] 12.1 13.4`

**2. Test**

```
print(myDataTable$input$getData)
```

Result (not as expected): `NULL`

**3. Test**

```
tempVal <- input$getData
print(tempVal)
print(myDataTable$tempVal)
```

Result (not as expected):

`[1]Temperature`

`NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're subsetting the data incorrectly, here are the 3 tests you have within the `observe` statement so you can see the output

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

lon <- c(50,51)
lat <- c(25,26)
Temperature <- c(12.1,13.4)
AirPressure <- c(1012,1011)

myDataTable <- data.frame(cbind(lon,lat,Temperature,AirPressure))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "getData",label = "used Data:",
              choices = c("Temperature","AirPressure"),selected = "Temperature"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observe({
    # Test 1
    print(myDataTable$Temperature)
    # Test 2
    print(myDataTable[,names(myDataTable) %in% input$getData])
    # Test 3
    tempVal <- input$getData    
    print(myDataTable[,names(myDataTable) %in% tempVal])
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: ok, very interesting: When I use your syntax as following: "myDataTable[,names(myDataTable) %in% input$getData]" it works. Mine doesn't ...

Comment: note that the `selectInput` is an object so you have to use it as such

Comment: I don't really understand the syntax. Never used this before.Where can I find some information how to read it? Are there some tags I can look for to understand whats happening here.

Comment: this is normal `r` syntax have a look at examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085806/extracting-specific-columns-from-a-data-frame