# Select columns with spaced heading in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I am sub-setting a dataframe by selecting specific columns. As in the example data below, one column heading (i.e. 80% height) is spaced.

```
df<-data.frame(x1=c(1020,2053,1840,3301,2094),
           x11=c(816,1642.4,1472,2640.8,1675.2),
           x2=c(584,187,746,177,483))
names(df)<-c("height","80% height","length")
```

I want to select the first two columns.
From the link [Extracting specific columns from a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085806/extracting-specific-columns-from-a-data-frame) one finds helpful discussion and solution about extracting specific columns in a dataframe. Following the link I tried several approaches including

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% subset(df, select=c(height,"80% height"))
```

but these end up with an error accompanied by the following message

```
Error in subset.data.frame(., df, select = c(height, "80% height")) : 
'subset' must be logical
```

I want to get this resolved. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use backquotes to select those unusual names i.e. column names that doesn't start with letters

```
subset(df, select = c(height, `80% height`))
```

-output

```
#   height 80% height
#1   1020      816.0
#2   2053     1642.4
#3   1840     1472.0
#4   3301     2640.8
#5   2094     1675.2
```

Also, the `dplyr` use with specifying `df` twice is not needed.  We can have `select` function from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     select(height, `80% height`)
```

-output

```
#   height 80% height
#1   1020      816.0
#2   2053     1642.4
#3   1840     1472.0
#4   3301     2640.8
#5   2094     1675.2
```

---

It may be also better to remove spaces and append a letter for those column names that start with numbers. `clean_names` from `janitor` does

```
library(janitor)
df %>%
    clean_names()
```